# Resize video based on flexbox wrap react bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to use flexbox to create a grid of videos and dynamically change video size. I'm using react bootstrap and if I put the width's in the video element as per below, the video takes up the width of the entire card and additional boxes (flex-items) end up outside of the card... If I use this exact code and remove the video element, I get the correct behaviour. **I think there is something wrong in the way I define the width or size of the video element.. how do I get it to resize smaller as new columns are added?** . Here's my code:

```
 <Container className="d-flex p-2 pt-4 justify-content-around">
        
         <Dot />
         <div className="col-lg-3" style={{maxHeight: dimensions.height}}> 
      
         <Card className="d-flex flex-wrap flex-column block-example border border-dark" style={{maxHeight: dimensions.height}}>  
       
         <video muted ref={userVideo} autoPlay playsInline style={{borderRadius: "10px", minWidth: "25%", maxWidth: "100%"}}/>    
  
         <div className="flex-item " >1</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">2</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">3</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">4</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">5</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">6</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">7</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">8</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">9</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">10</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">11</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">12</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">13</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">14</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">15</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">16</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">17</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">18</div>
        <div className="flex-item ">19</div>
        </Card>  
        </div>
        </Container>

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here's the behaviour with the code above:

[image]

I want the video to resize so that all the boxes fit in the grid-like this (shown without a video element):

[image]

Any help would be so much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Comment: Here you go, I've replaced the video with an image element. What I want is that the image width changes dynamically as columns are added. However, right now, the image width is fixed. You can see that when adding extra flex-items or removing them the widths for those elements are dynamically changing. 

https://codesandbox.io/s/flex-wrap-with-bootsrap-uvn1b?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The responsive video not related to bootstrap -- in general you could even create one div and one video to show you the problem. Try this "Famous" trick: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/responsive-videos/.  More ideas: https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-video/.